# Help with algebraic steps that my statistics text employed in confirming a conditional distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, bivariate

In the page from a statistics book pasted below the authors make the algebraic leap from the LHS to the RHS of the equals sign here:

$\large \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} - 2\rho_{12} \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)(x_2 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} = \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} \left[x_1 - \mu_1 - \rho_{12}\frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{12}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}(x_2-\mu_2)\right]^2 - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2$

... and I need help discovering the algebra employed to move from LHS to RHS of the equals sign.

As the text suggests, the above equation I need help with has on the LHS of its equals sign "The two terms involving $\large x_1-\mu_1$ in the exponent of the bivariate normal density [see equation (4-6)]" copied here ...

$\large \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}-\sigma_{12}^2}} \times \exp \left\{ -\frac{1}{2(1 - \rho_{12}^2)}\left[ \left(\frac{x_1 -\mu_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2 - \mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}\right)^2 -  2\rho_{12}  \left( \frac{ x_1 -\mu_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}\right) \left(\frac{x_2 - \mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}\right) \right] \right\} $

... and on the RHS the authors (Johnson, R.A, Wichern, D.W. (2007)) have put their algebraic transformation.

I assumed what the authors have done is to replace the unconditional mean $\large \mu_1$ and unconditional variance $\large \sigma_{11}$ on the LHS with the conditional distribution mean $\large \mu_1 + \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)$ and either of the two forms of conditional distribution variance $\large \sigma_{11} - \frac{\sigma_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}} = \sigma_{11}(1-\rho_{12}^2)$ that are shown for the conditional distribution on the previous page, $\large N\left(\mu_1 + \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2), \sigma_{11}-\frac{\sigma_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}\right)$.

I have tried for some time to do the same and I do enjoy this process, but after a long slog, I am unable to get to the RHS.

Just to be clear, I do not have trouble with equation (4.6) or with the steps after the one I am asking about.  I am trying to move from here $\large \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} - 2\rho_{12} \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)(x_2 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}$ to here $\large \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} \left[x_1 - \mu_1 - \rho_{12}\frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{12}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}(x_2-\mu_2)\right]^2 - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2$

Unfortunately, my algebra skills do not get me across the equals sign.  Apologies if this means that this is more of an algebra than statistics question.

The text is: Johnson, R.A, Wichern, D.W. (2007). Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis (6th Edition

[image: Johnson, R.A, Wichern, D.W. (2007). Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis (6th Edition). Pearson.]

Comment: This is a FAQ about algebra.  It's called [completing the square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complet*+square).  The awful notation obscures the simplicity of this result, which in elementary textbooks might be expressed in the form $ax^2+bx+c=a(x+b/(2a))^2+(c-b^2/(4a^2))$ for $a\ne 0.$

Comment: I see it now just in that form. Very helpful.

Comment: ... + (c - b^2 / (4a)) correct?

Comment: Right -- good catch.  I had mentally multiplied the last term by $a.$

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing intricate here happening. When you break the square in the RHS, from the square of the first term, you retrieve the first component in the LHS; the square of the last term is cancelled by the last term in the RHS. The 2ab term when multiplied by $1/\sigma_{11}$ will yield the second component in LHS.

But we need to go from LHS to RHS. From above, it can be noted that we only need to complete the square, an elementary method, to reach RHS.

Comment: Thanks User1865345. I will give what you suggest a try and if works for me, I will return with the lines I used so others can see as well.  Thanks for providing the breadcrumbs and not the path; gives me an opportunity to find my own way.

Answer (score 0):

Per User1865345's suggestion, I broke the square on the RHS of equals and worked my way back to the LHS, which worked fabulously.  Here I present the reverse of that since I was looking to move from LHS to RHS, but to be clear what I did in following the suggestion of User1865245 is the reverse of what's shown here:

$\begin{align} \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} -  2\rho_{12} \frac{(x_2 - \mu_2) (x_1 - \mu_1)}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} 
& = \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} - \frac{1}{(\sqrt{\sigma_{11}})^2} 2\rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) (x_1 - \mu_1) + \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{11}} \frac{\sigma_{11}}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2   - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2 \\
& = \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} - \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} 2\rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) (x_1 - \mu_1) + \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}}\rho_{12}^2 \frac{\sigma_{11}}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2   - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2 \\
& = \frac{(x_1 - \mu_1)^2}{\sigma_{11}} - \frac{2\rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) (x_1 - \mu_1)}{\sigma_{11}} + \frac{\rho_{12}^2 \frac{\sigma_{11}}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2}{\sigma_{11}}    - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2 \\
& = \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} \left[ (x_1 - \mu_1)^2 - 2\rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) (x_1 - \mu_1) + \rho_{12}^2 \frac{\sigma_{11}}{\sigma_{22}} (x_2 - \mu_2)^2 \right] - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2 
 \\
& = \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} \left[ (x_1 - \mu_1) - \rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) \right]\left[ (x_1 - \mu_1) - \rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) \right] - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2 \\
& =  \frac{1}{\sigma_{11}} \left[ (x_1 - \mu_1) - \rho_{12} \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}} (x_2 - \mu_2) \right]^2 - \frac{\rho_{12}^2}{\sigma_{22}}(x_2-\mu_2)^2
\end{align}$